# Easiest method to OrderBy a String using StringComparison.Ordinal

Tags: c#, string, compare, ienumerable, ordinal

I've found a bug (in my code) that results from [String.CompareTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w(v=vs.110).aspx) and binary search because my custom IComparer (for the wrapping type) uses `String.Compare(x, y, StringComparison.Ordinal)`.

This is because `items.OrderBy(i => i.Name)` (where Name is of type string) used to build the Array to search used the string object itself as the IComparable - and such has different rules:

> The comparison uses the current culture to obtain culture-specific information such as casing rules and the alphabetic order of individual characters. For example, a culture could specify that certain combinations of characters be treated as a single character, or uppercase and lowercase characters be compared in a particular way, or that the sorting order of a character depends on the characters that precede or follow it.

For example, {A, b, C} is sorted as `[A, b, C]` with the OrderBy-using-Default-String-Compare but should be `[b, A, C]` per the Ordinal comparison - since it is not, the binary search is failing.

Now, with the "context" out of the way,

What is the easiest (eg. without implementing a custom IComparer for strings) way to order the objects with string properties the same as with `String.Compare(.., StringComparison.Ordinal)`?

---

Edit: I [just realized I] can, and probably should, just use `OrderBy(x => x, theSameComparer)` - but supposing this wasn't possible, how can OrderBy be used with the same results?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a pre-built `StringComparer` that applies [`StringComparison.Ordinal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - that's [`StringComparer.Ordinal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
items.OrderBy(i => i.Name, StringComparer.Ordinal)
```

Comment: Ah, brilliant (or makes me seem dull): I assumed StringComparer.Ordinal was a constant - should have realized it was itself a comparer.

Comment: Ah, should of refreshed the page.  You beat me to it.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add `StringComparer.Ordinal` directly into your `OrderBy`.

```
string[] content = { "A", "b", "C", "d", "AB", "Ab" };
var ordered = content.OrderBy(o => o, StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

Then once you iterate through `ordered` you would receive the following output:

> ```
> // Output:
> A
> AB
> Ab
> C
> b
> d
> ```

I believe that is what your after.

Answer (score 2):

It worth mentioning, it can be used in `Array` and `List` sorting as well not just in `Linq`:

```
string[] content = { "A", "b", "C", "d", "AB", "Ab" };
Array.Sort(content);
//output: A,Ab,AB,b,C,d
Array.Sort(content, StringComparer.Ordinal);
//output: A,AB,Ab,C,b,d

var list = new List<string>{ "A", "b", "C", "d", "AB", "Ab" };
list.Sort(StringComparer.Ordinal);
//output: the same as array.srot and linq with Ordinal comparer
```