# Lexicographically sort C#

Tags: c#, sorting, lexicographic

I have this code for sorting strings:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        List<string> sampleList = new List<string>();

        for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
        {
            string word = Console.ReadLine();
            sampleList.Add(word);
        }


        foreach (string s in SortByLength(sampleList))
        {
            Console.Write(s);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> SortByLength(IEnumerable<string> e)
    {
        // Use LINQ to sort the array received and return a copy.
        var sorted = from s in e
                     orderby s.Length descending
                     select s;
        return sorted;
    }
}
```

This code sorting strings by length, how can I do that by length and lexicographically ?

Example

```
//Input
4
abba
abacaba
bcd
er

//Output
abacabaabbabcder
```

In this case work fine, but when I have

```
//Input
5
abba
ebacaba
bcd
er
abacaba

//Output
ebacabaabacabaabbabcder
```

My first string is ebacaba which is wrong.

Comment: You can try:
`var sorted = e.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).ThenBy(x => x).ToList()`

Comment: I don't understand the pattern you want to achieve for the second case (5 input), mind to give the expected output?

Comment: Use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28638804/235911

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:**

By default, the non-char is lexically smaller than the char, thus, you can exploit this and omit `ThenBy` but will still get the same result like this (Credit goes to [Matthew Watson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106159/matthew-watson)):

```
string str = "abba ebacaba bcd er abacaba output ebacabaabacabaabbabcder";
string[] strs = str.Split(' ').OrderBy(x => x).ToArray(); //same result, but shorter
```

**Original:**

Use `OrderBy` and also `ThenBy`

```
string str = "abba ebacaba bcd er abacaba output ebacabaabacabaabbabcder";
string[] strs = str.Split(' ').OrderBy(x => x).ThenBy(x => x.Length).ToArray();
```

You will get:

```
abacaba //aba is earlier than abb
abba
bcd
ebacaba
ebacabaabacabaabbabcder
er
```

Comment: I think you'll get exactly the same output if you leave out the `.ThenBy()`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson you are right! I just tested it. Seems like the non-char is lexically smaller than char

Comment: It's standard dictionary order, after all. Makes me wonder what the OP wants... Ah! Just realised! He wants to sort by length and THEN by value.

Answer (score 4):

You can use thenby :

```
static IEnumerable<string> SortByLength(IEnumerable<string> e)
{
    // Use LINQ to sort the array received and return a copy.
    var sorted = e.OrderByDescending(s=>s.Length).ThenBy(r=>r);                 
    return sorted;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to add how to sort just lexicographically?

Answer (score 2):

Change your function t:

```
static IEnumerable<string> SortByLength(IEnumerable<string> e)
{
        // Use LINQ to sort the array received and return a copy.
        var sorted = from s in e
                     orderby s.Length descending, s
                     select s;
        return sorted;
    }
```

Which will output:

```
abacabaabbabcder
abacaba
output
abb
bcd
edr
```

When used with `new List<string>{"abb", "abacaba", "bcd", "edr", "output", "abacabaabbabcder"}`

Because it will order by s.Length, then by s (lexical order)