# Why does C# OrderBy with string order lowercase before uppercase?

Tags: c#, string, list, character, ascii

I'm coding in C# and I had a situation that needed me to order a series of one character string.
example:

```cs
var list = new List<string> { "1", "A", "a", "0" };
```

Since we all know that the `ASCII` table lists Upper before Lower, I was expecting this to be ordered like this (0, 1, A, a), but it was ordered like this (0, 1, a, A)

I have a simple example:

```cs
        var strs = new List<string> { "1", "A", "a", "0" };
        var orderedStrs = strs.OrderBy(l => l);
        Console.WriteLine("---strs---");
        foreach(var elem in strs){
            Console.WriteLine(elem);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("---orderedStrs---");
        foreach(var elem in orderedStrs){
            Console.WriteLine(elem);
        }

        var chars = new List<char> { '1', 'A', 'a', '0' };
        var orderedChars = chars.OrderBy(ch => ch);
        Console.WriteLine("---chars---");
        foreach(var elem in chars){
            Console.WriteLine(elem);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("---orderedChars---");
        foreach(var elem in orderedChars){
            Console.WriteLine(elem);
        }
```

and this is the output:

```
        ---strs---
        1
        A
        a
        0
        --- orderedStrs---
        0
        1
        a
        A
        ---chars---
        1
        A
        a
        0
        --- orderedChars---
        0
        1
        A
        a
```

Can anybody answer me this question?

Comment: What country do you live in? And what language do you speak? Please specify in your question.

Comment: @mjwills, sorry, typo, fixed it! I live in Portugal. Do you think it's a regional issue?

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28638714/easiest-method-to-orderby-a-string-using-stringcomparison-ordinal and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/locale/sorting-and-string-comparison and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.compareto?view=netframework-4.8 ?

Comment: Nice! So it's not using the ordinal comparison? So why do the lower come first?

Comment: Why would you expect it not to? Where did the docs say that wouldn't happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OrderBy(a => a, StringComparer.Ordinal)`

```cs
var strs = new List<string> { "1", "A", "a", "0" };
var orderedStrs = strs.OrderBy(l => l);
Console.WriteLine("---strs---");
foreach (var elem in strs.OrderBy(a => a, StringComparer.Ordinal))
{
    Console.WriteLine(elem);
}
```

**result**

```
---strs---
0
1
A
a
```

Comment: Perhaps cite that page instead then (or mark it as a duplicate).

Comment: @mjwills Thank you, you are right. but i thought it best to answer this question Instead of a link or mark it as a duplicate question