# Why is "Test" greater than "test"

Tags: c#

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string t1, t2;
        t1 = "Test";
        t2 = "test";
        Console.WriteLine(t1.CompareTo(t2)); //prints 1, expected was -1
    }
}
```

So, it says that `CompareTo()` is supposed to return 1 - if it's greater than, -1 if it's less than or 0 if it's equal to the other string. In this example I am comparing "Test" with "test". As I understood, in ASCII, 'A' < 'a'.
So why does it say that t1 is greater if the only difference is first letter, and by ASCII, it should be smaller. Thanks.

Comment: There are many many ways of comparing characters. Perhaps the "ordinal" comparer gives you the ASCII definition of order?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does C# OrderBy with string order lowercase before uppercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60930562/why-does-c-sharp-orderby-with-string-order-lowercase-before-uppercase)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default C# string comparison (as in, if you don't specify it yourself anywhere) is a culture-aware comparison, and the rules depend on your computer's culture.

If you want to use ordinal comparison (ie ASCII as you call it, though C# strings are Unicode), you can use this instead:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(t1, t2, StringComparison.Ordinal));
```

Also note that the specification requires a negative, zero or positive result, not specifically -1. The command above will return -32 for example.

Comment: Interesting and unexpected "gotcha" of the language.

Comment: I wouldn't say unexpected, culture-aware string comparison and sorting is fully documented: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/locale/sorting-and-string-comparison.

Comment: Documented or not, it violates the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), at least to people familiar with other (or dare I admit, older) languages.